# Need to prove with empty set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

So I've been working on set theory lately, and I have been asking myself: Do I need to do every proof for the empty set?
For example; I need to prove that if $A\cap B=A$ then $A\subseteq B$. You can do that by saying that if $a\in A$ then $a\in A\cap B$, so $a\in B$. Thus, $A\subseteq B$. Does the assumption that $a\in A$ break the proof for the empty set? (As the empty set has no elements) Also, when I say $a\in B$ I'm assuming B has elements. I know that the proof for $A=\emptyset$ or $B=\emptyset$ is trivial (if $A=\emptyset$, for every set B $A\cap B=A$ and $A\subseteq B$; if $B=\emptyset$ then A must be $\emptyset$ so that $A\cap B=A$, and obviously $\emptyset \subseteq \emptyset$), but I don't know if I should show it in an exam.

Comment: It depends.  For instance the proof that "*If $A\times B = A\times C$ then $B=C$*" if you try to do this while ignoring the special case of the empty set you will have "proven" the result despite the result being false... $\emptyset\times \{1\}=\emptyset\times \{2\}$ for instance despite $\{1\}\neq \{2\}$.  The error in the proof usually lies with the fact that $a\in A$ and $b\in B$ implies $b\in C$ is not equivalent to $b\in B$ implies $b\in C$.... that is to say $P\wedge Q\implies R$ is not equivalent to $Q\implies R$

Comment: So, in your example I see it clear. I am confused with the example that I showed above.

Comment: So you have a statement that is supposed to be true for any set, including the empty set. Your proof however starts with the assumption that $A$ is nonempty. So you've only proven a part of the statement. The other case, when $A$ is empty has to be considered separately.

Comment: @freaksh: *Sometimes* one needs to consider the empty case separately. Not always. Not in this case. There is no assumption that the antecedent is true when one proves $(x\in A)\to (x\in B)$ by proving $x\in A\vdash x\in B$.

Comment: @freakish, the proof does not start with the assumption that $A$ is nonempty, it starts with the instantiation of a universal quantifier: to prove that "for all $a\in A$ also $a\in B$", we instantiate the "for all" by moving to an arbitrary $a\in A$ and then continue the proof. At the end, we can generalise this arbitrary $a$ to retrieve the universal quantifier. Nowhere in that process is it assumed that $a$ actually exists, or that it has any specific property; in fact, if we did, then it wouldn't be an arbitrary element anymore, since we would assume additional properties, like existence.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the example that you have mentioned, there is not need to consider the case $A=\emptyset$. When you write “if $x\in A$” you are *not* assuming that $A$ is not empty. It's just the beginning of a sequence of arguments that proves that *if* $x\in A$, *then* $x\in B$. In other words, you are proving that every element of $A$ is also an element of $B$, and that's what $A\subseteq B$ means.

Comment: I disagree. He proved that if $A\neq\emptyset$ then the statement is true. The case $A=\emptyset$ has to be considered separately as well for the proof to be complete.

Comment: Then tell me where the assumption that $A\ne\emptyset$ was used.

Comment: Right, but if I prove that every element of A is an element of B I'm not proving it for the empty set, right? Because there is no element of A that can belong to B whatsoever.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos quoting "You can do that by saying that if $a\in A$...". He didn't prove the case when there is no such $a$. He didn't even consider it.

Comment: As I wrote in my answer, the assertion $A\subseteq B$ *means* “every element of $A$ is also an element of $B$”; it as no exception for the case in which $A=\emptyset$. But if you disagree with me about the meaning of $A\subseteq B$, then tell me what it means to you.

Comment: Writing “if $a\in A$” does *not* assume that $A$ has some element. It's not as if he had written “if $A$ is not empty, then let $a$ be one of its elements.”

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I don't see anywhere in your answer the statement that $\emptyset$ is a subset of any set, including $B$. It is a simple statement, I agree, but without it the proof is incomplete.

Comment: @freakish I disagree. My proof is complete and there is no need to use the fact that $\emptyset$ is a subset of any set. If you think otherwise, then prove it.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos look at JMoravitz comment. Suppose we look at a different statement: "$A\times B=A\times C$ implies $B=C$". By your logic I can start with $a\in A$ and ignore the case when $A=\emptyset$ for which the statement is false.

Comment: @freakish: I'm with Jose. $A\subseteq B$ is equivalent to the statement $\forall x(x\in A\to x\in B)$. If we show $x\in A\vdash x\in B$ (which is what we are assuming is being done), then this is formally equivalent to proving $\vdash x\in A\to x\in B$, and then by Universal Generalization this yields $\vdash \forall x(x\in A\to x\in B)$, which is *literally* the same as $A\subseteq B$. There is no need to discuss what happens if $x\in A$ is never true.

Comment: @freakish: That proof is different. Using the same formal argument as I do above, you would succeed in establishing $\vdash \forall x(x\in A\to ( (A\times B=A\times C)\to (B=C))$. But this statement is *not* what we are trying to prove in that instance. What we are trying to prove is $\vdash (A\times B=A\times C)\to (B=C)$. That's why that proof does required a different argument or a special case.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I know that the proof is different. That's not the point. The point is that you cannot simply ignore the empty set. The fact that $\emptyset\subseteq B$ is vacously true is trivial, I agree, but not something you can just ignore and say "there is no need". Of course I understand that in practice many people do that, but I assume OP is asking about the formal approach.

Comment: @freakish: Please point out exactly which of the **mathematical** statements I made above about how proofs work and what one is proving is incorrect. I never talked about something being vacuously true or trivially true, so kindly do not erect strawmen. I'm sorry, but you are just plain *wrong* here. It's not a matter of "in practice" or "trivial". You are just wrong. I addressed the **formal** approach, and you, in contrast, *ignored it* to just reiterate your incorrect assertion.

Comment: @freakish: I am not "simply ignor[ing] the empty set." I am pointing out, **formally** and **explicitly**, why the proof given does not "ignore" the empty set, applies in full, and does not require, *in the formal sense* a separate consideration of the case in which $A$ is empty.

Comment: @freakish You are plain wrong. Here there is no reason to consider the empty set separately, and there hardly ever is in general.

Comment: There is no need to treat the empty set separately in this proof.  If you assume $x \in A$ and then prove $x \in B$, you are showing that if $x$ is an element of $A$ then $x$ is an element of $B$.  You are not claiming that anything actually is an element of $A$, so you are not assuming that $A$ is not empty.  You are simply considering, hypothetically, what *would* be true *if* something were an element of $A$.  And that is precisely what is required to prove $A \subseteq B$.